# how to check if an array has subkey in laravel test

Tags: php, laravel, testing

i have a multi dimention array that i want to write test for . i read on web that there was a function called `arrayHasSubKey` but it does not exists any more it seems . i am using laravel 5.8 and i want to check if this array has a subkey this is what my array looks like :

```
key =>value [
 key2 =>value2 [
  key3 => [
    key4 =>value4,
    key5=>value5
]
]
]
```

now i want to check if key2 or key3 exists on the array . how can that be done in a laravel test . thanks in advance

#EDIT

so according to the answer i changed my code to below :

```
  $testForKeys = [ 'key2', 'key3' ];
        $foundKeys = [];
        $array[] = 'key =>value [ key2 =>value2 [  key3 => [    key4 =>value4,    key5=>value5]]]';
        // Test to get the array
        array_walk_recursive($array, function ($value, $key) use ($testForKeys, $foundKeys) {
            if (in_array($key, $testForKeys) && !in_array($key, $testForKeys)) {
                $foundKeys[] = $testForKeys;
            }
        });
        // Get them in the same order
        sort($testForKeys);
        sort($foundKeys);
        $this->assertEquals($foundKeys, $testForKeys);
```

but when i run the test i get this error :

```
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
+    0 => 'key2'
+    1 => 'key3'
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a built-in way. You can use `array_walk_recursive` though;

```
public function yourTest() {
   $checker = function ($value, $key) use (&$checker, $testForKeys, &$foundKeys) {
       if (in_array($key, $testForKeys) && !in_array($key, $foundKeys)) {
           $foundKeys[] = $key;
       } 
       if (is_array($value)) {
           array_walk($value, $checker);
       }
   };

   array_walk($array, $checker);

   sort($testForKeys);
   sort($foundKeys);
   $this->assertEquals($foundKeys, $testForKeys);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but this is not working . it returns error

Comment: I've updated my answer. There were a few issues but mainly `array_walk_recursive` skips keys if their value is an array so I've used `array_walk` with a recursive step instead